# Spider Runs But Does Not Output Files

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

Wrote a code for a spider to search a site collect certain information. The spider runs but does not output the information in the required folders. Any idea why this might be the case. Please see the main code below, I didn’t include the URL link.

---

```
def parse(self, response):        
    prices = response.css('.price::text').extract() 
    titles = response.css('img::attr(alt)').extract() 
    images = response.css('img::attr(data-altimage)').extract() 
        for item in zip(titles, prices, images ):
            scraped_info = {
                'titles' :item[0],
                'prices': item[1],
                'images': item[2],
                }
            yield scraped_info
```

Comment: can you show all spider class ? where you save the data ? and how you save it

Comment: Spyder is an IDE; presumably you didn't mean that in your question title (instead, Spider)? Also, where is there supposed to be output to a file from this code?

Comment: Yes that is correct I meant spider, the output is in another file i.e. “setting.py”  which is on my personal PC. The code from the file is given below for your info                     --------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------FEED_FORMAT = "csv"
FEED_URI = “ooo.csv"


ITEM_PIPELINES = {
        'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1
}
IMAGES_STORE = 'tmp/images/'